# In django, how to disable the use of EmailValidator?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Base on `AbstractBaseUser`, I create my own profile. In the profile class, I define,

```
def nonfunc(self):
    pass

email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    primary_key=True,
    validators = [nonfunc,nonfunc],
)
```

I do not want to use the email validation from django and I disable html5 validation.

```
<form method="post"  novalidate>
```

But when I entered a invalid email and then submit the form, It returned 
`Enter a valid email address.`

How to exactly disable the django default email validation?

Comment: Why are you using EmailField if you don't want it to validate? Why not use a standard CharField?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought there would be some way to do it without changing the fact it is a emailfield.

Comment: @user18481 If you say that you want an email that is not necessarly an email that sounds weird. If it can be something else, better use a `CharField` as Daniel suggested.

Comment: @vmonteco sorry for the confusion. I do want an email. But I do not want to use EmailValidator. Later I will add my own validation by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`TextInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) widget for rendering.

## 1- If you use a modelform :

You should override the default widget by adding a `Meta` class :

```
class MyUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email',)
        widgets = {
            'email': TextInput(),
        }
```

## 2- If you use a simple `Form` :

Just use the widget instantiation parameter

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

---

It should turn this :

```
<input name="email" required="" id="id_email" type="email">
```

into this :

```
<input name="email" required="" id="id_email" type="text">
```

Therefore disabling the client's built-in email input validation.

**But :**

Keep in mind that it won't turn backend validation off. Only the frontend one. But since you only seem to try replacing the frontend validation with a homemade JS one, this should be fine.